# Detecting balanced parentheses

Tags: python, stack, balanced-delimiters

### Objective:

> Given a string `s` containing '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']' (and other
> characters), determine if the input string is valid.
>
> An input string is valid if:
>
> 1. Open brackets are closed by the same type of brackets.
> 2. Open brackets are closed in the correct order.

### Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path

import typer


def validate_brackets(s: str, brackets={"[": "]", "{": "}", "(": ")"}) -> bool:
    stack = []

    opening = brackets.keys()
    closing = brackets.values()

    for c in s:
        if c in opening:
            stack.append(c)

        if c in closing:
            if not stack or c != brackets[stack[-1]]:
                return False
            stack.pop()
    return not stack


def main(file: Path) -> None:
    with open(file) as f:
        print(validate_brackets(f.read()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

### Review Request:

General coding comments, style, bad practices, et cetera.

Comment: I like your usage of `typer` for the CLI.

Comment: A set of unit-tests would really help here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Permit me to add the following to the review posted by toolic:

### Use Docstrings

I would add a docstring to function `validate_brackets` describing its functionality.

### Create a `set` from `closing`

**Update**

I have done a little research into the implementation of the `dict_keys` class an instance of which is created with `opening = brackets.keys()` and checking `c in opening` should be more or less equivalent to checking `c in brackets`, which is to say efficient. So there appears to be no need to create a set from the keys. However, if we want to efficiently check to see whether `brackets.values()` contains duplicates, then it seems to me we should create a `set` from these values and verify that its length is the same as the number of keys. This should also speed up the check `c in closing`. We can check to see if the set of keys and the set of values are disjoint by using `opening.isdisjoint(closing)` (see the next section concerning validation).

### Sample Validation of the *brackets* Argument

Things you might test for:

1. The *brackets* argument is a non-empty `dict` instance.
2. `brackets.values()` contains no duplicate characters. Although this condition is not strictly necessary, it is the norm and we will enforce it.
3. The opening and closing characters should be disjoint.

The above validations are more easily performed when the closing characters are a set. This will also speed up the check `c in closing`. We will place the validation logic in a separate `validate_brackets_dict` function for greater readability. Since this function might be called repeatedly for the same `brackets` dictionary instance, we can cache previously-validated dictionaries in a dictionary whose key is a `frozenset` of the dictionary's items (since dictionaries are not hashable) and whose value is a tuple consisting of the opening and closing characters to be used.

I would also make the default value for the *brackets* argument to be `None` for which a default dictionary that requires no validation will be provided.

### Putting It All Together

With the above suggested changes, the final source could be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
import typer
from typing import Union, Dict # For older Python versions

default_brackets = {"[": "]", "{": "}", "(": ")"}
default_opening = default_brackets.keys()
default_closing = set(default_brackets.values())

validated_brackets_dict = {}

def validate_brackets_dict(brackets: Dict) -> tuple:
    """Validate the brackets dictionary and if valid
    return a tuple of the opening and closing characters to be
    used. Otherwise, an exception is raised."""

    if not (isinstance(brackets, dict) and brackets):
        raise ValueError('brackets must be a non-empty dict instance')

    cache_key = frozenset(brackets.items()) # We cannot cache a dictionary
    opening_closing = validated_brackets_dict.get(cache_key, None)

    if opening_closing is None:
        # Validating a brackets dictionary that we haven't seen before
        opening, closing = brackets.keys(), set(brackets.values())
        # Although ensuring non-duplicate closing brackets is not strictly necessary,
        # it is certainly the norm. So we can consider the following
        # check optional but desirable:
        if len(closing) != len(brackets):
            raise ValueError('Duplicate closing characters')
        # Check for closing characters disjoint from opening
        # characters:
        if not opening.isdisjoint(closing):
            raise ValueError('Opening and closing characters are not disjoint')
        # Cache for possible next time:
        opening_closing = (opening, closing)
        validated_brackets_dict[cache_key] = opening_closing

    return opening_closing

def validate_brackets(text: str, brackets: Union[Dict, None]) -> bool:
    """Determine if the input text argument contains balanced
    parentheses. The optional brackets arguments is a dictionary
    of "parentheses" key/value pairs to be used.
    If brackets is None then a default dictionary is used."""

    if brackets is None:
        brackets = default_brackets
        opening, closing = default_opening, default_closing
    else:
        opening, closing = validate_brackets_dict(brackets)

    stack = []

    for c in text:
        if c in opening:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c in closing:
            if not stack or c != brackets[stack[-1]]:
                return False
            stack.pop()
    return not stack


def main(file: Path) -> None:
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()

    print('text:', repr(text))
    print()
    # Some test case for validation:
    for brackets in (
        [],
        {},
        {'[': ']','(': ']'},
        {'[': ']','(': '['},
        {'[': 'x'},
        None
        ):
        print('brackets:', repr(brackets), end='')
        try:
            result = validate_brackets(text, brackets)
        except Exception as e:
            result = e
        print(', result:', repr(result))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

Prints:

```None
text: 'abc[xx]'

brackets: [], result: ValueError('brackets must be a non-empty dict instance')
brackets: {}, result: ValueError('brackets must be a non-empty dict instance')
brackets: {'[': ']', '(': ']'}, result: ValueError('Duplicate closing characters')
brackets: {'[': ']', '(': '['}, result: ValueError('Opening and closing characters are not disjoint')
brackets: {'[': 'x'}, result: False
brackets: None, result: True
```

Comment: @bob The idea was to not waste cycles performing validation on a value of `brackets` known to be valid.

Comment: Ah yes you’re right, I’m not sure what I was thinking. Lol. ‍♂️

Comment: @muru Good point about that confusion, but I'd instead improve the comment.

Comment: I would like to note that the constraint that no two closing brackets must be equal is unnecessary for the problem at hand.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, that constraint is not strictly necessary. But don't you think that it would be desirable? It is also the norm.

Comment: @Booboo: It is the norm in programming yes, so I can see why it could be useful.

Comment: I have updated the post with a separate method `validate_brackets_dict` that does the validation of the passed `brackets` dictionary and caches the computed `opening` and `closing` characters so if a successive call to `validate_brackets` is made with the same `brackets` dictionary (highly likely) nothing has to be recomputed.

Comment: JSON seems kinda odd for this. How about a frozenset of the dict items? I think that's the usual solution.

Comment: @KellyBundy If you mean that the key of the cache should be a frozenset of the dictionary's items, then really all you need is `cache_key = tuple(brackets.items())`, which is cheaper than computing a frozenset.

Comment: That distinguishes different orders, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy True, but a user will have defined a `brackets` dictionary and then will use the same dictionary repeatedly rather than passing a different dictionary with the same key/value pairs but in a different insertion order. If you are truly concerned, then you can use `sorted(tuple(brackets.items()))`. Me, I am not concerned.

Comment: Probably, yes. But I'd still use a set out of principle.

Comment: @KellyBundy I did a benchmark of using a `frozenset` vs. what I was doing and the `frozenset` not only is key-insertion-order independent, it is faster and so I made the change.

Comment: @Booboo Interesting. I would've guessed the opposite. Tried it myself, also got frozenset being faster.

Answer (score 10):

The code layout looks good, and you gave the functions and variables meaningful names.

That being said, you could consider using longer variable names for the single-letter ones.  Perhaps, `text` instead of `s`, for example.

You should consider checking the inputs to the `validate_brackets` function.  For example, I assume that you do not want to support the case where the opening and closing bracket is the same character, like `[` and `[`.  This code returns `True`:

```
print(validate_brackets('[aaa]', {"[": "["}))
```

If you do add checking for this case, then you can use `elif` for the `closing` condition since they are mutually exclusive:

```
    if c in opening:
        stack.append(c)
    elif c in closing:
```

I also recommend adding header comments describing the overall functionality and if there are restrictions on the inputs.

If you have not done so, adding some basic unit tests would be beneficial.

Comment: I had actually started with `text`, but changed it to `s` as per the specification later. :)

Comment: +1 about names. It would make the code a lot easier to grasp at a glance. Instead of “stack” what about an explanation of what c represents, e.g. “unterminated_brackets” or something similar?

Comment: @bob Such a long name would make the code harder to read. And "stack" is a pretty good name. If I see this task and then see the word "stack", I immediately know what they're going to do (unless they do something weird instead of the usual).

Comment: It is a long name and there’s probably a way to shorten it, but naming it for what it holds rather than for what it is will greatly enhance readability. If it’s called stack, the reader has to mentally reverse-engineer the algorithm to understand it as stacks can hold all sorts of things. If it has an indicative name that cognitive burden is reduced.

Comment: @bob *"If it’s called stack, the reader has to mentally reverse-engineer the algorithm to understand it"* - I wouldn't call it reverse-engineer. When I saw that name, not only did I know that it's a stack, but I also (correctly) predicted what it will hold and how it will be handled, as that's the straightforward way to solve this and similar tasks and I've seen or used it many times. And then I only had to read the code and confirm the prediction. Note I'm not saying the name `stack` is always this useful and sufficient. But here I think it is.

Comment: To each their own.

Comment: *"I assume that you do not want to support the case where the opening and closing bracket is the same character, like [ and [."* << In the case of `[`and `[` it does seem weird but quotes are usually opened and closed by the same character,  `"` or `'`, so this wouldn't be such a unusual use-case and I see no reason to prevent the user from doing it, ***if*** this is handled correctly. For instance, `"[]"()"[]"` should return True but `"["()"]"` should probably return False (presuming the dict is `{'[':']', '(':')', '"':'"'}`). A docstring should also indicate whether this is accepted to not.

Comment: @Stef `"["()"]"` looks correct to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh. I actually agree. Still, a docstring would be welcome to clarify whether this is handled or not.

Answer (score 3):

Minor improvement maybe: Replacing

```
if not stack or c != brackets[stack[-1]]:
    return False
stack.pop()
```

with:

```
if not stack or c != brackets[stack.pop()]:
    return False
```

Comment: I’m not sure eliminating a line is beneficial here as it could make it easier to miss an important state-modifying operation: stack.pop(). Personally I’d leave that on its own line, and possibly even comment it as long as the comment wasn’t “pop the next item off the stack.”

Comment: @bob It's not about eliminating a line (although I do see that as a benefit as always, as it allows another line to fit on the screen instead). It's about eliminating a wasteful access. And using what `pop()` returns, instead of throwing it away. Comment the pop()? For something this trivial? That would just be distracting.

Comment: `if not stack: return False`; `match = stack.pop()`; `return c == brackets[match]` might be better.  That avoids side-effects buried in the `or`.

Comment: @TobySpeight That doesn't work, the second `return` must be conditional as well. I don't think it's hidden/buried the way I put it, but ok. How about `if not stack or stack.pop() != c:` then? After pushing not the opening parentheses but their counterparts needed to close them.

Comment: Yes.  Still, as a general rule, I try to avoid side-effects inside conditionally-executed parts of expressions (`and`, `or`, `x if c else y`, etc).  "Try to avoid" doesn't mean at _all_ costs, though!  I agree with pushing the expected close symbol - I think that's how I would write this function to start with, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fair enough. I knew it's not for everybody. After all, that's why I said "maybe", despite the benefits.

Answer (score 3):

#### Separate out the brackets

There's a bit of preprocessing necessary for the brackets:

- Validation
- Separation of keys and values

You can just preprocess the brackets again and again and again each time the function is called, but it's quite a waste of time when the user will, most likely, pass the same specification every, single, time.

The solution in such a case is to create a `Brackets` class, and perform all the preprocessing in its constructor.

The user is then free to pass the same instance over and over, or not to bother and just create it from scratch every time, or something in-between.

```py
class Brackets:
    def __init__(self, brackets: dict[str, str]):
        self.__brackets = brackets
        self.__open = frozenset(brackets.keys())
        self.__close = frozenset(brackets.values())

        #   You may or may not wish to impose that closing brackets are
        #   distinct from one another. It is not strictly necessary though.

        if not self.__open.isdisjoin(self.__close)
            raise ValueError(f'Opening and closing characters are not disjoint in {brackets}')

    def is_open(self, c: str) -> bool:
        """Returns whether `c` is an opening bracket"""
        return c in self.__open

    def is_close(self, c: str) -> bool:
        """Returns whether `c` is a closing bracket"""
        return c in self.__close

    def is_matching(self, open: str, close: str) -> bool:
        """Returns whether `close` is the matching closing bracket of `open`"""
        return self.__brackets[open] == close

DEFAULT_BRACKETS = Brackets({"[": "]", "{": "}", "(": ")"})
```

Then, the function becomes:

```py
def validate_brackets(s: str, brackets: Brackets=DEFAULT_BRACKETS) -> bool:
    """Returns whether `s` has balanced brackets, or not.

    A string has `s` has balanced brackets if ...
    """

    stack = []

    for c in s:
        if brackets.is_open(c):
            stack.append(c)
            continue

        if not brackets.is_close(c):
            continue

        if not stack or not brackets.is_matching(stack[-1], c):
            return False

        stack.pop()

    return not stack
```

Comment: -1 because of useless over-engineering

Answer (score 3):

The code is lean and maintainable. There are minor issues:

#### predicate naming

Predicates shall start with e. g. `is_...` or `has_...` so that
`True` and `False` are natural answers.

#### useless locals

There is no need for

```
opening = brackets.keys()
closing = brackets.values()
```

as you can test for membership directly at no extra cost. Also the names do not help, `brackets` is a well introduced variable and is comparable in reading length. Also the locals miss the plural. Reading code is simpler if there are less names.

#### dict.keys()

Instead of testing for

```
some_var in brackets.keys()
```

you test for

```
some_var in brackets
```

#### Parameter `brackets`

I dislike the parameter as it is calling for errors. The function fails if the user does a typo.
Also there might be a genius using the function to test for closed strings by passing

```
is_valid(s, brackets={'"': '"'})
```

Either

- make brackets a constant
- or limit the function parameters to explicitly named bracket types

  `is_valid(s, brackets=True, braces=True, parentheses=True)`

So you can test your function for all parameters.

#### Documentation

Add a one liner docstring explaining what is the meaning of "valid".

Comment: What's your replacement for `c in closing`?

Comment: @KellyBundy edited to clarify - it is a generic advice.

Comment: So it's `c in brackets.values()`? I find that less nice, but ok. Though *"at no extra cost"* is not true. Made the whole solution ~20% slower in my testing.